# comparing columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is my table structure.

```
TableA
ID int
note varchar(600)
```

*eg Data*

```
1     this is my first note.
2     blah blah
1     this is my first note.
1     second note.
```

note column can have duplicate data.

I want to count how many data are duplicated group by ID with the result as ID, count.

eg.

ID   count

1      2

Comment: Are you just asking for the count of ID's if they are duplicated?

Comment: no , I just want to know how many duplicate entry that each user ID has been made. so, I can trace back the duplicate entry note list.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), ID, note 
FROM TableA
GROUP BY ID, note 
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand, but I think this will do what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),id,note
FROM TableA
GROUP BY id,note
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```